# how to Iterate through list of ids and insert a record in table for that each id in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Hi I have a list of ids say 1,6,8,9,12,45,67,....
I want to iterate through these ids and insert a record in table for each id example -

```
for each id {
  insert into table_name(user_id, sys_id, crt_tsp) values (nextval,{this value is from above list}, current_timestamp)
}
```

how can I achieve this in sql my database is oracle?

Comment: Put that list in a temporary table. JOIN.

Comment: Is you lists of ids from a table? If yes, you can do this by a query, If not, you can create a stored proc

Comment: Where is this list (A file, in an array in some language, in a table?). In which language were you planning on writing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a collection. `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` is a built-in `VARRAY` you can use:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/262e9/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  user_id NUMBER,
  sys_id  NUMBER,
  crt_tsp TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name;

INSERT INTO table_name( user_id, sys_id, crt_tsp) 
SELECT sequence_name.NEXTVAL,
       COLUMN_VALUE,
       current_timestamp
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 1,6,8,9,12,45,67 ) );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/262e9/1/0)**:

```
| USER_ID | SYS_ID |                    CRT_TSP |
|---------|--------|----------------------------|
|       1 |      1 | 2018-05-14 14:14:08.157393 |
|       2 |      6 | 2018-05-14 14:14:08.157393 |
|       3 |      8 | 2018-05-14 14:14:08.157393 |
|       4 |      9 | 2018-05-14 14:14:08.157393 |
|       5 |     12 | 2018-05-14 14:14:08.157393 |
|       6 |     45 | 2018-05-14 14:14:08.157393 |
|       7 |     67 | 2018-05-14 14:14:08.157393 |
```

Or you can create your own type:

```
CREATE TYPE NumberList IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

INSERT INTO table_name( user_id, sys_id, crt_tsp) 
SELECT sequence_name.NEXTVAL,
       COLUMN_VALUE,
       current_timestamp
FROM   TABLE( NumberList( 1,6,8,9,12,45,67 ) );
```

**Update**:

From the OP's comment on another answer:

> I want to get the list of numbers from another table
>
> ```
> select id from table_name
> ```

You can just select directly from that table:

```
INSERT INTO table_name( user_id, sys_id, crt_tsp) 
SELECT sequence_name.NEXTVAL,
       id,
       current_timestamp
FROM   table_name;
```

Comment: Thank you .I want to get the list of numbers from another table . example . .....FROM  TABLE( NumberList(select id from table_name)); But i keep getting error below SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 - "missing expression"

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @MT0's answer, in Oracle 12.2 and above, you don't even need  `TABLE`function, you can directly select from `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` or `FROM NumberList(1, 6, 8, 9, 12, 45, 67)`

```
INSERT INTO table_name (
    user_id
    ,sys_id
    ,crt_tsp
    )
SELECT sequence_name.NEXTVAL
    ,COLUMN_VALUE
    ,current_timestamp
FROM SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 6, 8, 9, 12, 45, 67);
```

If you are ok to pass a comma separated list of numbers enclosed within a **string**, `XMLTABLE` may also be used (works in 11g)

```
INSERT INTO table_name (
    user_id
    ,sys_id
    ,crt_tsp
    )
SELECT sequence_name.NEXTVAL
    ,to_number(COLUMN_VALUE)
    ,current_timestamp
FROM XMLTABLE('1, 6, 8, 9, 12, 45, 67');
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to get the list of numbers from another table . example ..FROM SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(select id from table_name); But i keep getting error below SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Comment: @question_tech : "the list of numbers", is it stored as id in multiple rows or one row as string?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo-code for an anonymous block that will do as you ask. You need to create a temp table with the ID's you want.

```
declare
  cursor c0 is
    select 
    a.id_value,
    b.user_id,
    b.crt_tsp
    from temporary_table a
    join data_table b on b.id_value = a.id_value;

begin
for rec in c0 loop
  insert into table_name (...) values(rec.id_value, rec.user_id, rec.crt_tsp ...);
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Why not just use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM temporary_table` and you can get rid of the entire PL/SQL block, cursors and loops? But, then you can also ask how does the OP get the list into the temporary table and you have a chicken-and-egg problem that this does not solve.

Comment: I like your answer a lot. It's more efficient if there's no additional logic. But your answer doesn't allow him to iterate through the ID's as requested by OP. Mine does.

Comment: That would be useful information to add to your answer as to the benefits of this version as opposed to something simpler - you could add a comment to the snippet indicating where you would perform the pre-processing in the loop or a simple example of some additional logic.